# Inject model instance in every route

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I have an RESTful api that most of the time should be aware of an particular model instance (fetched from mongodb) depending on the context.

Is there a way, may be through a middleware, so I can have that object in some accessible from all routes place? I was thinking of overloading the `req` variable but there might be some better way.

What I have in mind is actually something similar to [Laravel's Route Model Binding](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-model-binding)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `app.param` too set a model instance on `req`